# Mocha Chai custom comparison function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, integration-testing, chai

I'm completely new to Mocha and Chai. I've created a function for comparing two objects in my test.

```
function compareExtremelyCompexObject (testedObject, trueObject);
```

How do I write a Mocha Chai spec that uses my `compareExtremelyCompexObject` function to assert the test?

I've got something like this:

```
it('should create a specific complex object from boilerplate data', function(done) {
  importDataFromSystem().
    .end(function(err, res){
          var dummyComplexObject = getBoilerplateComplexObject();
          compareExtremelyCompexObject(res, dummyComplexObject);
          done();
      });
    });
});
```

The examples I've found until now are missing how to compare a complex object. Can it be achieved with "should"/"expect"?

Let me know if this is not clear enough. I have really been researching this issue for days. Any help will be profoundly appreciated!

Comment: "I need to test a function named importDataFromSystem, which imports data from an external system, manipulates it, and finally stores it in DB.", you shouldnt have a simple function doing all this job, its literally untestable, you need to split this into atleast 3 functions, 1 imports the data, pass it into one that manipulates the data and pass it into one that stores the data, like that you can easily test each one of the 3 functions, what you are trying to do is probably doable but with much more work than you should

Comment: @rule I do have a separate function for each task (importing, manipulating and storing), but still I also need to test the entire process (the "director"). Don't I? Because it might does something wrong at the macro level

Comment: ohh ok , i thought you were trying literally to test a single function doing all that in a single test! Well you can test the full process but i dont know how hard that will be , i dont really have a helpfull input related to that, sorry.

Comment: There are *dozens* of ways to do that kind of comparison and I've probably used all of them in different contexts. Oftentimes the choice between one way or another is really a matter of personal preference. Sometimes the specifics of the project are going to make one way better than the other but you are not providing specifics here. Your question is therefore primarily opinion-based and not a good fit for this site. You should pick an approach and ask a question if you run into trouble.

Comment: @Louis you completely misunderstood my question. I didn't ask for best practices, but for any solution that works. I'm just very new to Mocha and Chai.

Comment: @Alon Ok, so your question is too broad. Primarily opinion-based and too broad often overlap.

Comment: @Louis opinions have nothing to do with my questions. I just need to build an integration test and I practically don't know how to do it. I need any answer that works, I didn't ask what's a better approach or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should edit your question a bit, to simplify, but from what I gather, you want to assert your new object === test object with your custom function?  If that's the case, and assuming `compareExtremelyCompexObject` returns true or false, you're almost there.

```
it('should create a specific complex object from boilerplate data', function(done) {
  importDataFromSystem()
    .end(function(err, res){
          var dummyComplexObject = getBoilerplateComplexObject();
          // with assert
          assert(compareExtremelyCompexObject(res, dummyComplexObject));
          // or with chai expect
          expect(compareExtremelyCompexObject(res, dummyComplexObject)).to.be.true;
          done();
      });
    });
});
```

As per your comment, the way you have `importDataFromSystem` chained, implies that it returns a stream, promise or itself.  Let's say its a stream which calls a callback on 'end' then `res` is likely what you're looking for so the example above should work.  However, if `res` isn't what you're looking for, then you might have to resolve a promise and chain the thenables to ensure a synchronous order of operations. eg.

```
it('should create a specific complex object from boilerplate data', function(done) {

  Promise.resolve()
    .then(function(){
         return importDataFromSystem();
    })
    .then(function(){
         return assert(compareExtremelyCompexObject(getNewlyCreatedObject(), getBoilerplateComplexObject()));
         // assert should throw error and be caught if the two objects are not equal
    })
    .then(function(){
         done()
    })
    .catch(function(err){ 
         done( err ); 
    });

});
```

But of course, you need some way to *get* the object you created.  That's a whole other discussion.  You should edit your question to narrow down the subject to just dealing with the assertion of a custom comparison. (or risk downvotes, and I'll probs get downvoted by proxy. =] )