# Use custom function for validation Mocha/Chai

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm new to testing with Chai/Mocha. I have a custom function that validates a string using a regex(for example). I want to use this function. Here's my code:

```js
describe('Custom Function', () => {
    it('Function 1', () => {
        // I'm calling a function here which returns a string, I want to validate that(only as example)
        expect(someFunction())
    });
});
```

This may seem very simple but I'm new to this, so sorry about that. Now, about the example validation function, I know I can use `.to.match(/SOME_REGEX/)` but I'm using the same function elsewhere and I don't want to duplicate code. My function will fetch data from an API and validate the result of the test accordingly

Not a duplicate of - [Mocha Chai custom comparison function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40890779/mocha-chai-custom-comparison-function)

Answer (score 0):

You can use to.be.true and you can use RegExp.test() method for exemple :

```
const regex = /^(H|HH)/;
expect(regex.test(string)).to.be.true;
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I have a function that will generate a string. I want that string to be validated by another custom function(suppose that function sends data to an API and the api validates it).